# reading multiple csv files using data.table doesn't work when given files path, possible bug?

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I want to read multiple csv files where I only read two columns from each. So my code is this:

```r
library(data.table)

files <- list.files(pattern="C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PROJECT\\NAME\\venv\\RawCSV_firstBatch\\*.csv")

temp <- lapply(files, function(x) fread(x, select = c("screenNames", "retweetUserScreenName")))
data <- rbindlist(temp)
```

This yields `character(0)`. However when I move those csv files out to where my script is, and change the `files` to this:

```r
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
#....
```

My `dir()` output is this:

```r
[1] "adjaceny_list.R"        "cleanusrnms_firstbatch"
[3] "RawCSV_firstBatch"      "username_cutter.py"
```

everything gets read. Could you help me track down what's exactly going on please? The folder that contains these csv files are in same directory where the script is. SO even if I do `patterm= "RawCSV_firstBatch\\*.csv"` same problem.

EDIT:
also did:

```r
files <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PROJECT\\NAME\\venv\\RawCSV_firstBatch\\",pattern="*.csv")
#and
files <- list.files(pattern="C:/Users/XYZ/PROJECT/NAME/venv/RawCSV_firstBatch/*.csv")
```

Both yielded empty data frame.

Comment: What happens if you `cd` to the folder and use `*.csv` in `list.files`?

Comment: What happens if you do `C:/Users/XYZ/PROJECT/NAME/venv/RawCSV_firstBatch/*.csv` ?

Comment: Thanks @linog, same thing hapens. data 0 obs, 0varibales. temp List of 0.

Comment: Hi @NelsonGon, then it works works (cd meaing the setwd right?). But then I have to re-do the cd to script where the R packages are. Otherwise rest of the script doesn't run

Comment: Do something like: `list.files("./path/folder",pattern="*.csv$")` Use `..` or `.` as required.(Not sure about using actual path). Can also utilise `~`

Comment: @NelsonGon, yeah this is the workaround I think I will have to make. Like setwd() to folder first, read everything, and setwd to default one. That will work. Thank you sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@NelsonGon mentioned a workaround:

> Do something like: list.files("./path/folder",pattern="*.csv$") Use ..
>   or . as required.(Not sure about using actual path). Can also utilise
>   ~

So that works. Thank you. (sorry have 2 days limit before I tick this as answer)